# Distrust wifi networks by default

Tags: network-manager

How can I configure Network Manager to default to **not** automatically connecting to any WAP that I've connected to in the past? Meaning, if I want NM to autoconnect to a WAP, I want to manually configure that, for each and every WAP that I want it to autoconnect to.

IMO, it is a horrible flaw that NM 'trusts' any WAP I connect to. I want to autoconnect to my home WAP, or my friend's WAP, but if I connect to "Starbucks Free Wifi" while I'm there, I **do not** want NM to autoconnect the next time it sees that network.

Answer (score 0):

NM will only Autoconnect if the profile is explicitly configured to do so *and* you connected to the network at least once successfully.

Whether a profile is configured to autconnect, depends entirely on the user who created the profile. It's the client tool that sets the setting. But indeed, all client tools default to enable autoconnct, you'd have to explicitly tell them otherwise, one by one. How to do that, depends on how you create the profile.

In nmcli, you can change an existing profile with

`nmcli connection modify "$PROFILE" autoconnct no`